# Proving a generated $\sigma$ field

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

If $U_q := \{Z \le q \}$ where $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $Z$ is a random variable, then how can I formally prove that $\sigma (Z) = \sigma (U_q : q \in \mathbb{Q})$?

This seems intuitive, but I struggle with formal proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be clear that $\sigma(U_q:q\in\mathbb{Q})\subseteq\sigma(Z)$, so we only need to show the other inclusion. To arrive at the other inclusion it suffices to show that $Z^{-1}(B)\in \sigma(U_q:q\in\mathbb{Q})$ for all $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (why?).

To this end, first show that
$$
\mathcal{E}=\{B\subseteq\mathbb{R}\mid Z^{-1}(B)\in \sigma(U_q: q\in\mathbb{Q})\}
$$
is a sigma-algebra on $\Omega$ ($\Omega$ being the set on which $Z$ is defined). Note that $\{(-\infty,q]: q\in\mathbb{Q}\}\subseteq \mathcal{E}$ trivially and hence also, since $\mathcal{E}$ is a sigma-algebra, 
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\sigma(\{(-\infty,q]: q\in\mathbb{Q}\})\subseteq\mathcal{E}.
$$
Now conclude.